# Ubuntu 17.10 won't start

Tags: 17.04

I can not access the login screen after I upgraded my ubuntu from 17.04 to 17.10. Ubuntu tries to restart immediately I start entering my password. 2. Restart too cannot complete, no matter how long I wait.

Tags : authentication 17.10

Comment: Troubleshooting those situations will take a lot longer then installing from scratch.

Comment: You can try inserting a recovery disk (an install disk, but without doing an install), then mounting your drive and looking in var/log/ for errors.  Like var/log/syslog.

Comment: Instead of entering your password, try CTRL-ALT-F7 and see if you can log in without the GUI.  Then you can troubleshoot the problem from the command line.  CTRL-ALT-F1 tries to restore/restart the GUI.

Comment: You can also see errors in the terminal by typing `dmesg`.

Comment: How to troubleshoot from command line? Actually I'm new to linux, can you guide me through it? @GlenPeterson

Comment: @BaibhabDebnath if you're new to linux and it won't start on an install and simply installing again doesn't fix it, your best bet is to find someone you know who can help.  Or find a LUG (Linux Users Group) near you on Meetup or through a web search.  Any LUG should be very friendly to someone walking in with a non-working laptop.  If they don't meet for a while, someone might be willing to meet you over lunch.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?  Your question says 17.10, it contains the words, "Tags: authentication 17.10", yet it's tagged 17.04.  In the question it says you "UPGRADED" from 16.10 to 17.10.  I thought that to do that you'd have to first upgrade to 17.04.  This confuses me.  Did you mean that you INSTALLED 17.10 on top of 16.10?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I upgraded from 17.04 to 17.10. And I have a dual boot with Windows 10. After the upgrade, when I open Ubuntu, the login screen comes, and after clicking on the username, before entering the password itself, it says 'authentication error'. And a black screen comes, where on the top right corner, it is written 
" Starting PackageKit Daemon...
[OK] Started PackageKit Daemon.
Starting Mange, Install and Generate Color Profiles...
[OK]Started Mange, Install and Generate Color Profiles. "